# What to split my String using `preg_split`

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, preg-split

This is my Original String :-

```
$data = "<br />
Q.156)  Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: <br />
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department <br />

<br />
Q.157)  Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: <br />
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department <br />
<br />
Q.158)  Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: <br />
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department <br />
<br />
Q.159)  Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: <br />
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department <br />
<br />
Q.160)  Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: <br />
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department <br />
<br />
Q.161)  Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: <br />
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department <br />
<br />
Q.162)  Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: <br />
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department <br />
";
```

I want to split my String as array in this format

```
Array (
[0] => Q.156) Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: 
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department 

[1] => Q.157) Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: 
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department 

[2] => Q.158) Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: 
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department 

[3] => Q.159) Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: 
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department 

[4] => Q.160) Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: 
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department 

[5] => Q.161) Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: 
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department 

[6] => Q.162) Direction (156–160): Study the given pie-charts carefully to answer the questions that follow: 
Breaking up :- Number of Employees working in Different Departments of an Organisation, the Number of Males and the Number of Employees Who Recently Got Promoted in Each Department 
)
```

I know I can use `preg_split('/[Q[.]]+/', $data)`

But I am little weak in regex .
Please help me my regex to incorporate Accordingly..

Comment: no , I have to keep break tags.

Comment: @chris85 great work ....  But I need something generic like `Q.1234)`  as you see there is integer after . ("/d")  .. Now what will be final regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `preg_match_all` will be a better function for you since you want to match each line.

```
preg_match_all('/Q\.\d+.*/', $data, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/pWs6c

Your regex was looking a little too loose, `[Q[.]]+` is creating a character class allowing `Q`, `[`, or `.`. The `]` is then attempted to be matched more than 1 time because the `]` is the literal character. You could use `[.]` on its own to match a single period, or `\.` is the same.

`\d` is a number.
`.*` allows for zero or more of any character, excluding a new line so this captures each of your question lines.

If you need the trailing line as well you can use this modified regex.

```
/(Q\.\d+.*?)(?:(?:<br \/>|\n){3}|$)/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Joo8wt/1/

This approach uses the `s` modifier so the `.` extends.

Comment: No, using your regex I am getting my desired output.. Thanks

Comment: Oh, great. I posted an update as well accounting for the other scenario.